# Split sql string value based on 7th delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Present column value

(Below is column value from temp table, value here is dynamically changing)

```
45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg | TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc
```

Need to divide based on 7th PIPE i.e after Test Msg

Output should be

String1

```
45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg
```

and (as a second string)

String 2

```
TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00......... etc
```

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SUBSTRING_INDEX
(
   @str NVARCHAR(4000),
   @delim NVARCHAR(1),
   @count INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
BEGIN
   DECLARE @XmlSourceString XML;
   SET @XmlSourceString = (SELECT N'<root><row>' + REPLACE( (SELECT @str AS '*' FOR XML PATH('')) , @delim, N'</row><row>' ) + N'</row></root>');
RETURN STUFF
(
    ((
        SELECT  @delim + x.XmlCol.value(N'(text())[1]', N'NVARCHAR(4000)') AS '*'
        FROM    @XmlSourceString.nodes(N'(root/row)[position() <= sql:variable("@count")]') x(XmlCol)
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE
    ).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(4000)')), 
    1, 1, N''
);
END
```

GO

```
DECLARE @EmpId NVARCHAR(1000)
select @EmpId = temp from OMSOrderTemp


SELECT dbo.SUBSTRING_INDEX(@EmpId, N'|', 7) AS Result;e
```

Here in Result only string1 is showing and only first row.

Comment: Please add tags for the specific database you are using.

Comment: In general string functions various from database to database so tag the DBMS you are using to get proper answer

Comment: use a while loop and charindex and store in a table. then output as you like

Comment: can you please explain.

Comment: anyone can please help me on this

Comment: This is the same you posted the last time @Somashekhar Kendule. Even you didn't mark that as answer :D It's hard to understand whether the answers help you or not. Even this one is easy to solve. Just try a little to get it work. By the way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried and wrote a function but it is giving only the first String1 value.
I want to get the both the value. Input string will contain many value bt output should be String1 is fixed till 7th PIPE and string2 output will be unlimited.

Comment: Edit your post and put the query that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spend time for you and happy that come with solution , I have modify the your function with own logic you can try this, This is table value function i.e this function will return Table

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SUBSTRING_INDEX
(
  @str NVARCHAR(4000),
  @delim NVARCHAR(1),
  @count INT
)RETURNS @rtnTable TABLE 
(
   FirstString  NVARCHAR(2000),
   SecondString NVARCHAR(2000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cnt INT=1;
    DECLARE @subStringPoint INT = 0
    WHILE @cnt <=@count
    BEGIN 
            SET @subStringPoint=CHARINDEX(@delim,@str,@subStringPoint)+1
            SET @cnt=@cnt+1
    END

    INSERT INTO @rtnTable
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,0,@subStringPoint-1) ,SUBSTRING(@str,@subStringPoint+1,LEN(@str)) 
    RETURN
END
```

To call this function

```
DECLARE @s varchar(MAX)='45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg | TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00'
SELECT * FROM dbo.SUBSTRING_INDEX (@s,'|',7)
```

This will gives two column output

```
45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg    TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00
```

Comment: Hey thank you its working fine. But its not working when we give input value as any table column value. 

I'm using your function as below..

Comment: DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(1000)
select @s = temp from Tempdata


SELECT * FROM dbo.SUBSTRING_INDEX_1(@s, N'|', 7)

Temp is column from tempdata Table

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution almost identical to @JaydipJ. I thought to implement in a different way but the following should do using `While` loop:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000), 
        @str1 VARCHAR(1000), 
        @str2 VARCHAR(1000), 
        @pos INT, 
        @counter INT 

SET @str = '45 | 00055 | 9/30/2016 | Vodafone | Randy Singh | Newyork | Test Msg | TBL101 | PC | 1.00 | COMP101 | CS | 1.00.............. etc' 

SET @counter = 0 
SET @pos = 0 

WHILE @counter < 7 
BEGIN   
SET @pos = CHARINDEX('|', @str, @pos + 1) ---- Gets the position of delimiter '|'
SET @counter = @counter + 1 ---- Increments the counter on the given counter value
END 

SET @str1 = SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @pos) ---- Splits the string on the 7th position of delimiter '|'
SET @str2 = SUBSTRING(@str, @pos + 1, LEN(@str) - @pos) ---- Splits the rest of the string

Print 'str1='+ @str1 
Print 'str2='+ @str2 

SELECT @str1 AS String1, @str2 AS String2
```

The `While` loop is used to iterate through the string and getting the `Delimiter` position, it splits the string.

Comment: Thanks mate. !! How should I pass @str as dynamic value here.

Comment: Just declare a variable at the beginning for str and counter. It'll work fine for dynamic values. For the
ease, static values are given. By the way, I did like to recommend you to mark as answer to @JaydipJ's answer as he has given the first one. That's really a good sign for the community :)

Comment: AT-2016 

Im trying to assign by using given code

SELECT @Str = [temp] FROM TempTable. it is giving only one value, but table contains many resulted values.

Comment: I guess, you should start a new thread for this @Somashekhar Kendule. Already this one was a headache :D Or edit your post with more details. But better would be starting a new thread if it's totally different from this. In the variable str, try to include the select query like `SELECT * FROM Table`. I am not sure if this works. But give a try.